# Best algorithm to tell if an odd semi prime exists between a given pair of even semi primes.

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps, semiprimes

**Problem:**

Let two even [semi primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiprime) be $2q_1$ and $2q_2$:
you are to find if any $n$ exists such that $n$ is odd , $n$ is semi-prime and $2q_1 < n < 2q_2$. We don't need to know the $n$ , we just need yes or no answer.

**My approach:**

The approach I can think of is:

$$
\pi(2q_2/3)-\pi(2q_1/3)\\
\pi(2q_2/5)-\pi(2q_1/5)\\
\pi(2q_2/7)-\pi(2q_1/7)\\
\vdots \\
\pi(2q_2/p_k)-\pi(2q_1/q_k)$$

i.e. primes under $2(q_2-q_1)$ times.

If any of these lines is non-zero answer is yes.

$\pi$ is Exact [Prime-counting_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function)

The computational complexity of this would be = O(number of primes under [2(p_2-p_1)] * complexity of best known exact prime counting function). = $O(n/log(n).(n^{2/3}/log^2(n)))$ = $O(n^{5/3}/log^3(n))$

My approach is definitely extremely inefficient, looking for better ones.

**Edit:**

The approach which @Peter suggests to traverse through all numbers in the range has time complexity $O(n.n^{1/4})$ = $O(n^{5/4})$ which isn't much efficient either.

Both the above approach uses no additional memory[ie $O(1)$ memory complexity] . For sake of simplicity we can assume we have infinite memory for any pre-computation/offline processing that you can think of.

Comment: This is probably impossible to solve without checking the numbers in the interval whether they are a semiprime.

Comment: I can't comment or attempt with your current notation, please fix it.

Comment: @Peter Can you speak in terms of computational complexity for what you mean by "without checking the numbers" . The naive  Idea that I mentioned has a computational complexity of O(number of primes under [2(p_2-p_1)] * complexity of best known exact prime counting function). = O($n/log(n) . (n^{2/3}/log^2(n))$) = O($n^{5/3}/log^3(n)$)

Comment: @Peter naive most idea would be to factorise all numbers from $2p_1$
 to $2p_2$
. whose computational complexity would be $(().n^{1/4})
=(^{5/4})$
 is that what you meant ?

Comment: @Peter The first approach is more efficient till billion and possibly till $n=10^{12}$
 due to the additional $log^3(n)$ division factors even though the power of $n$ is more. But as we go higher and higher the second one outperforms the first.

Comment: @DLeftAdjointtoU I am not very comfortable with mathjax, I couldn't find a suitable notation, so reverted to plain english. Maybe now you can comment.

Comment: @sibillalazzerini fixed the $\LaTeX$ for you.  Please edit post to view the changes and learn how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

The major optimization is to use approximate formulas for maximal prime gaps to return `yes` when `p1` and `p2` are far apart. Specifically https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Numerical_results provides maximal prime gaps for numbers up to `2^64` (e.g. the maximal gap for numbers below 10^9 is 114, so if `2/3(p2-p1)>144` and `p2<10^9` you can just return true. For larger values explicit gaps aren't known, but there are useful upper bounds on gap sizes. Specifically, the prime gap at `n` is always less than `3(n^2/3+n^1/3+1)` for x>e^e^15 by https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2113.

There are also a number of much stronger conjectures on prime gaps. With the Riemann hypothesis, the maximal gap can be lowered to `O(sqrt(n)log(n))`, and there are even stronger conjectures of `O(log(n)^2)` (although these are much more controversial).

After this, I think your best bet is to just do your approach with a few differences. The main one is that you can compute `pi(x)-pi(x+delta)` efficiently by doing `delta` primality checks. You also don't have to search as many ranges as your original estimate since most of the intervals won't contain any numbers.

Also, it's worth noting that given the various conjectures on prime gaps, it's very likely that if there isn't a prime in `(2/3p1, 2/3p2)` then they are very close together.

Comment: Theories about Prime gaps are probabilistic. If there ware any deterministic formula for prime gaps then there would be deterministic formula for primes. Can you elaborate in your answer what you meant by using conjectures on prime gaps? Also I didn't get what is meant by `pi_lo` and `pi_hi`?

Comment: Is this clearer? I removed the bit about `pi_lo` and `pi_hi` since I'm pretty sure the maximal prime gap results are stronger.

Comment: You have a database with exact $\pi(n)$ in a very large range of values. So you already have a catalog of primes in this range of values. If you search number of semi-primes between $a$ and $b$, and if you need to repeat this for many couples $(a,b)$, probably the best is to build a catalog with all semi-primes in this range of values.  You build this catalog one time, and you just have to read this catalog for any couple (a,b)

Comment: the key point is that the table stores manual prime gaps. this is a strictly monotonic function and grows slowly. as such, you can store this function work only about 100 constants while storing all the primes in this range would be completely impossible.

Comment: What's the time complexity ? I need exact answer not something with $O(log(n)^2)$ error as your answer suggests.

Comment: conjunctures about primes  gaps don't make any deterministic algorithm. Twin primes are just 2 numbers apart and you can get them anywhere. You can't build a deterministic (exact answer) algorithm using it.